# ESLINT error 'props' is assigned a value but never used

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I understand ESLINT helping to clean up my code and find it useful however I have found a scenario I am unable to resolve without and dummy console.log statement.

In the scenario, I receive a prop containing **modelValue** however only **modelValue** is updated in an event and ESLINT complains that **props** is defined but never accessed.

```html
<template>
      <q-header bordered class="bg-white text-black">
      <q-toolbar>
        <span class="lt-md">
            <q-btn dense flat round icon="menu" @click="toggleLeftDrawer" />
        </span>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>
</template>

<script setup>

/*
  emits
*/
const emit = defineEmits(['update:model-value'])

const toggleLeftDrawer = () => {
  emit('update:model-value', !props.modelValue)
}

/*
  props
*/
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`modelValue` is a state passed down to this component, which from your shared snippet is not used anywhere as of right now.

The emits that you have in other places of your code are actual strings aka not the `modelValue` variable.

TLDR: `modelValue` != `'modelValue'`

Comment: modelValue is passed from the parent via a prop and the child updates the value in response to a click event in the child which updates the value in the parent. The code works.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events

Comment: Copy `modelValue` in your code editor, then look for it in your file. As you would notice, there is nothing else using that variable (besides it's declaration). This is the only thing that ESlint is telling you. Even if there may be some magic regarding how things are bind, here: `'update:model-value'` have nothing to do with the variable `modelValue` @Dercni

Comment: modelValue is OK. It's the props declaration that ESLINT complains about:
"error  'props' is assigned a value but never used"

Comment: Oh yeah, so same thing: do you use `props` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I mean, if you `console.log(props)`, you should not have this error/warning. But we don't have more info as of your setup or a [repro], so I can just take what you're saying as granted. But it should not complain so far. @Dercni

Comment: Added my template. The console.log removes the error however is this good practice?

Comment: One thing to understand here, is that ESlint is giving you hints on what you're doing. So, if you're declaring a variable that you're not using, ESlint will suggest to either use it or just remove the variable (to not have unused memory + dead code). Doing one or both is fine. Even tho, you usually want to access props in some way down the road with your template/script section. If you don't but don't like having a warning there and you're not using `props`, you can always disable ESlint for that specific section of your code. No good or bad practice per-se, just a reminder for you. @Dercni